# Aparte de los verbos que expresan fenómenos meteorológicos, ¿existen otros verbos impersonales en español?

Tags: verbos, solicitud-de-término, oraciones-impersonales

Un verbo impersonal es, por [definición](https://dle.rae.es/verbo#5T94JRP), un verbo que se emplea generalmente en la tercera persona de singular de todos los tiempos y modos, simples y compuestos, y en infinitivo y gerundio, sin referencia ninguna a sujeto léxico elíptico o expreso. Normalmente se suele asociar a verbos que expresan fenómenos meteorológicos, como *llover*, *nevar*, *granizar*, pero también [*molliznear*](https://dle.rae.es/molliznear), [*ventiscar*](https://dle.rae.es/ventiscar), [*tempestar*](https://dle.rae.es/tempestar), [*atardecer*](https://dle.rae.es/atardecer), [*orvallar*](https://dle.rae.es/orvallar), [*rociar*](https://dle.rae.es/rociar), [*nortear*](https://dle.rae.es/nortear), [*alambrar<sup>2</sup>*](https://dle.rae.es/alambrar) y decenas de verbos similares.

Sin embargo, ¿existen verbos impersonales que no se refieran a este tipo de fenómenos?

Answer (score 4):

<sub>Esta es una lista parcial. Es una publicación *wiki*, por lo que siéntete libre de editar para añadir, mejorar, reformatear, y asi tendremos una lista más o menos exhaustiva y única. Eso sí, si añades nuevos verbos asegúrate de incluir un enlace al sitio que certifique su uso como impersonal. ¡Gracias!</sub>

- [**Haber**](https://dle.rae.es/haber).

  - Como "ocurrir": *Hubo una hecatombre.*
  - Como "celebrarse": *Ayer hubo junta.*
  - Como "ser necesario": *Habrá que salir a pasear.*
  - Como "existir": *Hay hombres sin caridad.*
- [**Hacer**](https://dle.rae.es/hacer).

  - Para expresar el tiempo que hace: *Hace calor.*
  - Para expresar el tiempo que ha pasado: *Hace tres días.*
- [**Picar**](https://www.rae.es/dpd/picar).

  - Según el DPD existe un uso coloquial impersonal cuando la parte del cuerpo se expresa mediante un complemento adverbial: *Le picaba en la espalda y me pidió, por favor, que lo rascara.*
- [**Bastar**](https://www.rae.es/dpd/bastar).

  - Según el DPD se puede construir como impersonal si se acompaña de un complemento introducido por *con*: *Bastaría con dar un golpe a la lápida para romperla.*

Answer (score 0):

Añadiendo a los anteriores:
avenir
cerner
parecer
poner

Comment: te animo Leo a añadir estas opciones en la [respuesta wiki](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/35678/1674), para tenerlo todo junto y, así, más fácil de leer

Comment: Yo también te animo, pero en todo caso si vas a añadir opciones a la respuesta wiki, por favor enlaza documentación que corrobore que esos verbos se pueden usar como impersonales. En el caso de _avenir_ y _parecer_ yo también he visto que en anteriores versiones del DLE aparecían algunas acepciones como impersonales, pero como en la última edición se quitó esa marca, pues no los incluí.